# lookup / store 2d as int,double[400][400] array in android fast

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to store/access and lookup some int and double value in a [400][400] array.
The previous code executes very slow. I heard that a byte array is no advance and i
need int and double values.
Why takes it so long in android? These are very primitive data types.
How can i do this in an efficient way?

```
public static double[][]mat_cost = new double[400][400];
ArrayList<Point> pixel = new ArrayList<Point>();
ArrayList<Double> pixelValue = new ArrayList<Double>();

int[][]mat_binaer = new int[400][400];

for(int w = 0;w<400;w++){//x                        
    for(int h = 0;h<400;h++){//y
        mat_cost[w][h] = 0;
        if(mat_binaer[w][h]==0){
            pixel.add(new Point(w,h));
            pixelValue.add(startValue);
        }
    }
}
```

It takes 44798 ms = 44,798 s.
Should I use another data structure like pointers in c?
How could i realize it in java for android?

Comment: How long does it take, and how do you know the slow part is the arrays?

Comment: it takes 44798 ms = 44,798 s

Comment: 160000 `Point` allocations and 320000 `ArrayList` adds is a lot of work, with GC kicking in every now and then.

Comment: should i use a normal array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are my results of the current state of my knowledge:

I found out that normal arrays are faster and you could store often changing data
in a relatively small array. Let me expain it.

I initialize the array like this:

```
        int startValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        public static Point[]pixel = new Point[471004];
        public static int[]pixelValue= new int[471004];
        int count = 0;
        for(int w = 0;w<200;w++){//x                        
            for(int h = 0;h<200;h++){//y
                mat_cost[w][h] = 0;
                if(mat_binaer_0[w][h]==0){

                    pixel[count]=new Point(w,h);
                    pixelValue[count]=startValue;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
```

And then I define an Index_first as the first Pointer of the first element in
my big arraylist and an Index_last as the last Pointer of my big arraylist.
If you change the elements often, like delete the first one or add elements at 
the end, you have to create these indices with another class. It's called
Index_Rotate:

```
public class Index_Rotate {
    private int index;
    private int array_position;
    public Index_Rotate(int index, int array_position){
        this.index= index;
        this.array_position = array_position;
    }
    public void inkrement(){
        index++;
        if(index>=471004){
             index = 0;
             array_position++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you delete or add something from your arraylist, you have to inkrement() the
first or the last index of your arraylist with this method. The instance of
Index_Rotate exists therefore two times. 
But be careful, if the array_postion of the first element smaller than 1 and the
index of the first pointer is smaller than the index of the last pointer, 
elements would be overwritten.

Nevertheless is the first allocation of 471004 elements very slow.
I tried it on an emulator with the allocation of only 39953 elements, because
the application requires only this amount at the beginning.
The above loop takes 3.5 seconds.

And now:
I tried the same in c# on visual studio:
There I added  281334 elements and allocated them with this loop:

```
        double startValue = Double.MAXVALUE;
        LinkedList<Point> pixel = new LinkedList<Point>();
        LinkedList<double> pixelValue = new LinkedList<double>();

        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
            {
                if (infomatrix[w, h] == 0)
                {
                    pixel.AddLast(new Point(w, h));
                    pixelValue.AddLast(startValue);
                }
            }
        }
```

These are LINKEDLIST as you can see and these are much more elements
(9 times more). This code only runs 0.0715 seconds. It's a very big difference.

My question: Why is the android code on emulator much more slower than the c# 
code on visual studio? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: okay, i have replaced the pixel-Points with x and y arrays and it helped. In android the same code tooks only 0.7 seconds.

Comment: if you need the full code implementation, how to rotate arrays, please ask me

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned in the comments, it's more likely that `pixel`, `pixelValue`, `new Point(x,y)` and `Double.valueOf(double)` are slowing things down. All of them are causing a lot of load on memory allocator and garbage collector.

- `new ArrayList<>()` allocates an arraylist with zero capacity. Each time you exceed that capacity, the list is [expanded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a2b1f08f3a1a1e06fddd357024901ff9e421af16/luni/src/main/java/java/util/ArrayList.java#114), starting at a capacity of 12 and then doubling each time. A new backing array is created at the new length, all items are copied, and the old array comes up for garbage collection. I can't tell from the code how often `mat_binaer == 0`, but for 160000 items, I suspect you may be looking at a whole lot of ArrayList expansions. If you have a reasonable guess as to how many items you'll have to add, preallocate the ArrayLists at that size, like e.g. `new ArrayList<>(1600)` if you expect 1600 items.
- Each time you add a primitive `double` to an `ArrayList<Double>`, it is wrapped in an object using `Double.valueOf()`. Each of these wrappings allocates an object on the heap. Using a `double[]` would be much more efficient than using an ArrayList.
- Likewise, every `new Point(x,y)` causes object allocation. If you need the xy coordinates, but not specifically as `Point` objects, then having two `int[]` arrays of the same length, one for the x's and one for the y's, will be much memory efficient.

This memory allocation stuff is the usual suspect for slow code, but in all performance tuning questions, you should as much as possible try to measure before changing stuff, for example, using [`systrace`](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html).

Comment: okay, i change my code into normal Arrays, which allocates Memory at the beginning of the programm and not every cycle of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented it as a java project and not android.
It is no difference. The allocation doesn`t waste time.

It`s all because of the emulator that slows everything down.